# ComplexityObject ksoap2 Android Magento error

Tags: java, android, magento, soap

I'm trying to use ksoap2 in order to create an order on a remote Magento installation. I'm able to perform basic operations with the SOAP v2 Api but I got stuck on a complexity object.

This is the part of the wsdl I'm trying to interface with

```
<complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntityArray">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:shoppingCartProductEntity[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<complexType name="shoppingCartProductResponseEntityArray">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogProductEntity[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
.....
<message name="shoppingCartProductAddRequest">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="quoteId" type="xsd:int"/>
<part name="products" type="typens:shoppingCartProductEntityArray"/>
<part name="storeId" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
.....
<operation name="shoppingCartProductAdd">
<documentation>Add product(s) to shopping cart</documentation>
<input message="typens:shoppingCartProductAddRequest"/>
<output message="typens:shoppingCartProductAddResponse"/>
</operation>
```

I tried the following

```
env = getEnvelope();
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, MethodName_AddProduct);
request.addProperty("sessionId",_SessionId );

SoapObject SingleProduct = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntity");
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("product_id");
pi.setValue(Products[0][0]);
pi.setType(String.class);

SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("sku");
pi.setValue(Products[0][1]);
pi.setType(String.class);

SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("qty");
pi.setValue(1);
pi.setType(Double.class);
SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
EntityArray.addProperty("productData",SingleProduct);

request.addProperty("quoteId",cartId);
request.addProperty("productsData",EntityArray);
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SoapAction_AddProduct, env);
```

But I get the following message

> SoapFault - faultcode: '1021' faultstring: 'Product's data is not
>   valid.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

I've also tried to print the request that seems correctly formatted to me

> DEBUG REQUEST :
>   shoppingCartProductAdd{sessionId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
>   quoteId=31; productsData=shoppingCartProductEntityArray{productData=shoppingCartProductEntity{product_id=1;
>   sku=PLM01; qty=1; }; }; }

Comment: i think you need to pass same parameters name that are mentioned in your wsdl

Comment: What are you referring to exactly? The wsdl states that the shoppingCartProductEntityArray should be named products, right?

Answer (score 2):

I got it, it was thr "productsData"

Complete code Below

```
env = getEnvelope();
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, MethodName_AddProduct);
request.addProperty("sessionId",_SessionId );
request.addProperty("quoteId",cartId);


SoapObject SingleProduct = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntity");
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("product_id");
pi.setValue(Integer.parseInt(Products[0][0]));
pi.setType(Integer.class);

SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("sku");
pi.setValue(Products[0][1]);
pi.setType(String.class);

SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("qty");
pi.setValue(1);
pi.setType(Double.class);
SingleProduct.addProperty(pi);

SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
EntityArray.addProperty("products",SingleProduct);

request.addProperty("products",EntityArray);
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```